# Can you append to a file using the alpakka HDFS connector?

Tags: scala, hdfs, alpakka

I'm trying to use this connector to pull messages from Kafka and write them to HDFS. Works fine as long as the file doesn't already exist, but if it does then it throws a FileAlreadyExistsException. Is there a way to append to an already-existing file using this connector? I'm using an `HdfsFlow.dataWithPassThrough` flow, and it takes an `HdfsWritingSettings`, but that only allows you to set an `overwrite` boolean; there's no `append` option.

Comment: Please create a ticket - or even better a PR :) - for this feature in the alpakka issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! https://github.com/akka/alpakka/issues/1236